# Querying posts that don't have a certain key value or don't have the key

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

The intention is to search for customers who do not have coupon X or do not have any coupon.

```
    $query = array (
        'post_type'      => 'clients',
        'meta_query'=> array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
               'key' => 'cupom',
               'value' => $idCupom,
               'compare' => '!=',
        ), array(
              'key' => 'cupom',
              'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
              'value' => '',
        )),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
```

I am doing according to other answers I found on the web, but the query returns wrong when it finds a post that has a meta_value different from the one searched.

Comment: why did you write `'key' => 'cupom'` ?

Comment: Note that this will be an expensive query that gets exponentially more expensive as the post meta table gets larger. You never want to tell the DB what you don't want, you want to tell it what you do want. Also, never set `posts_per_page` to `-1`. Give it a high number you never expect to reach, but never `-1`

Comment: @swartex 'cupom' is the meta_key i want to search and compare

Comment: @tomjnowell this is a revers query because i want to add post meta on clients don't have 'cupom'

Comment: if it's a one time task then you would be better off with a WP CLI command and fetching all the posts, then checking in PHP, paging through them in batches

Comment: @tomjnowell This query should occur every time a new coupon is generated.

Comment: That sounds extremely expensive/slow/cumbersome. I'm guessing the result of this query is that you'll then make some DB writes? That'll put an upper limit on how many posts/coupons you can have as eventually it will take longer to process than there is time to save. Are you sure that post meta is really the appropriate solution here? I would sit down and redesign how this data is stored, I would advise but there's not enough info to do so in this question. Also, if the coupon has only just been created, then wouldn't this query give the same results as `WP_Query(['post_type' => 'clients'])`?